# Migrating currently installed system (20.04) to new hardware

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, live-usb, backup, cloning

I just built a new computer and want to migrate my existing Ubuntu 20.04 installed system upon it. A fresh install is out of question since I got quite a complex system with tons of personalizations and additional packages, customized docker containers, and whatnot.

I know that it's a question already asked, but all existing answers seem to be somewhat outdated.

Here is what I found till now:

- Use tools like ***remastersys*** or ***respin*** to create a bootable live iso of the installed system.
- Use ***clonezilla*** to clone the system (but will it work upon the new, different hardware?)
- Do a fresh install and then use ***Aptik*** to recreate the environment (but Aptik need a paid license)

I'd like to know:

1. Which is the fastest and **more reliable** method for my use case?
2. Are there better alternatives?

**NOTE**: Judging from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254072/transferring-a-new-system-to-new-hardware), it seems that a fresh install is always recommended not to incur in performance issues.
**So let me ask: would creating a live iso from your existing system (and then installing it) be equivalent to a fresh install?**

Comment: Not sure if it is very viable, but the way I did mine for relocating to a new drive was a fresh install and then copy the entire ext4 file system contents to the new drive.. worked for me.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt: Did that restore all the stuff pertinent to your configuration? If so, can you give the details about how did you (quoting) "copy the entire ext4 file system contents to the new drive"? 
One thing that leaves me perplexed is that in your "old" ext4 file system there could be settings/files pertinent to the old hardware configuration. That would spoil the deal, since it would actually be even worse than a blind cloning with clonezilla.

Comment: hardware for me stayed the same, the only difference was the drive was swapped. The only hardware configuration you really have to worry about is if you are going from AMD to NVIDIA or vice versa for your GPU, or if you are going from 32 bit to 64 bit CPU or vice versa. Without that, nothing really changes. If you are doing either of those, then either remove the existing graphical drivers or only copy over files that are customised - i.e not system files that are critical to the ext4 system like your home directory or apps you installed (if you can).

Comment: just clarifying: before copying over the ext4 system if your GPU changed, make sure to boot the old system and delete proprietary graphical drivers. Make sure you `purge` where necessary otherwise it will still leave trace files.

Comment: I also believe in new install. But you should re-configure new install from your normal backup. Then you know your backup includes everything you need when hard drive fails and you only have backup to restore from. All user configuration is in /home. You can export list of installed applications and maybe some settings in /etc. I copy a couple of files in /etc to /home just for backup. If any server applications database or web,  those will have folders in / (root) that need backup also.

Comment: Plug your old HDD into your new computer and give it a try. If it is perfect for your needs, just clone it to the new SSD using `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb` where sda is your old HDD and sdb is your new SSD. Update to a new LTS as you normally would, no rush.

Comment: @MaybeLBDidIt: I have to go from a system with Intel cpu and nvidia turing gpu to a system with AMD cpu and nvidia ampere gpu.. I dunno if that will screw things...

Comment: @C.S.Cameron. Thanks, will try that.

Comment: @oldfred: Thanks, I'll try the blind hdd transfer first. If it doesnt work as it should, I goo for a new install with the cares you recommended.

Comment: Mhhh.. Guys, will copying with `dd` preserve the block alignment upon the ssd?

Comment: Is old drive gpt & UEFI? And exactly same size as new drive? You use dd to copy a drive that is exactly the same number of sectors. Often HDD & SSD of same size are not quite same number of sectors.

Comment: @oldfred: Not at all. The old drive is 512gb. The new one is 1.92Tb. Old drive is gpt, but I see no obstacles in making the new one gpt too.

Comment: You will convert 2TB drive to 500GB. You then will have to use gdisk to move backup gpt partition table that is at end of drive to true end of new drive & resize partition(s). You cannot reboot with both drives connected as duplicate UUIDs are not allowed. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ To move backup to end of drive
 launch gdisk, then type x, then type e, then type w to save your changes  I still believe new install & restore from backup is easier.

Comment: When I dd from small drive to large drive I just use GParted to expand root partition.

Comment: @oldfred: Thanks, man. It's a bit too involved for my taste. I'll definitely go for a fresh install.